# .Net core controller does not work with dependency injection

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

I'm currently trying to make a project from this article
http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/36340.create-a-web-api-application-in-asp-netcore.aspx#Introduction

All works fine except one thing

I have a MoviesController class, which has constructor with DbContext parameter

```
    public class MoviesController : Controller
{
    private readonly MovieDbContext _context;

    public MoviesController(MovieDbContext context)
    {
        _context = context;
    }
```

And here is method from Startup class, where this injection must be resolved

```
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddDbContext<MovieDbContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));

        // Add framework services
        services.AddMvc();

    }
```

the problem is that each time I call this controller, the browser gives me the following error: *HTTP 500 error
That’s odd… the website can’t display this page* with no additional info.
When I remove the parameter from c-tor, it works well.
MovieDbContext class

```
public class MovieDbContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Movie> Movies { get; set; }
    public MovieDbContext(DbContextOptions<MovieDbContext> options) : base(options)
    { }
}
```

Hope for your help

---

Edit

appsettings.json

```
{
    "ConnectionStrings": { 
    "DefaultConnection": "Server=(localdb)\\mssqllocaldb;Database=movieDB;Trusted_Connection=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=true"
    },

  "Logging": {
    "IncludeScopes": false,
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Debug",
      "System": "Information",
      "Microsoft": "Information"
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Your title is different to the error you describe.

Comment: do you have class MovieDbContext? Please include  it to the question.

Comment: What exactly is the error?

Comment: My bet is that there is some exception thrown during the creation of the MovieDbContext instance, before the constructor of your controller is called. You could verify this, by checking if a breakpoint in the constructor his hit. Does the console window of Visual Studio show some exception details ?

Comment: @rboe well, I didn't use VS, so I couldn't look through the debug trace. I did the debug in VS and I got one excpetion, null argument passed into the class

Comment: @demaskinas - the same information should be logged on the console window, where you started 'dotnet run'

Comment: @rboe I discovered that the problem is in Configuration.GetConnectionString method. I hold my connection string in appsettings.json and trying to get it out from there by GetConnectionString. But it returns null value, I don't know why. I tried to specify the string directly just by putting "mystring" argument instead of GetConnectionString and it works. But the method returns null.

Comment: Can you show also appsetting.json?

Comment: @mww at the bottom of the post

Comment: Put also Startup class and you have added `Microsoft.Framework.Configuration.Json` package?

Comment: looks similar: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40821459/asp-net-core-dbcontext-issue